# JButton margins. Not respected when nimbus plaf

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, nimbus, uidefaults

The property `margin` of a `JButton` isn't respected when the nimbus look and feel is installed. 
.
I need some "little" buttons, but nimbus forces the space around button text to be large, so I only get "very large" buttons. 
I discovered in [nimbus defaults page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/_nimbusDefaults.html) that there is a property called:

```
Button.contentMargins
```

that is preset with large values.
I've tryed to override it with the following code:

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("Button.contentMargins", new InsetsUIResource(0,0,0,0));
```

in the `main`, just after setting the nimbus look and feel.

But nothing happens, the empty space around buttons text still remains large.
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altering the value of the `JComponent.sizeVariant` may also be effective, as discussed in [*Resizing a Component*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/size.html).

Answer (score 2):

on base of thread [How to change the background color for JPanels with Nimbus Look and Feel?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8265872/714968) is possible to change and assign one value for something from `Nimbus Defaults`,

but are you sure that you needed this output to the GUI, nothing nice

[image]

v.s. basic JButton with Nimbus L&F

[image]

from code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource;

public class NimbusJPanelBackGround {

    public NimbusJPanelBackGround() {
        JButton btn = new JButton("  Whatever  ");
        JButton btn1 = new JButton("  Whatever  ");
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(btn);
        p.add(btn1);
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.setSize(200, 100);
        f.setLocation(150, 150);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo laf : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(laf.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf.getClassName());
                    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Panel.background", Color.white);
                    UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults().put("Button.contentMargins", new InsetsUIResource(0,0,0,0));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                NimbusJPanelBackGround nimbusJPanelBackGround = new NimbusJPanelBackGround();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

previously +1 for interesting question