# Positioning panel vertically centrally in grid layout

Tags: java, swing, alignment, grid-layout

I am trying to build a sudoku puzzle with grid layout to the contentpane and adding my Cell objects(extends JPanel) to it. However, I am not able to align the components vertically centrally. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357720/java-vertical-alignment-within-jpanel

Comment: The example [cited here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12625532/230513) uses `GridLayout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your content pane instead to use an other layout manager, e.g. `GridBagLayout` and add to it the `GridLayout` panel that holds all your Cell objects. This way your sudoku panel will be centered and its contents (the cells) will not expand to fill the whole area.