# how to change Java Swing Nimbus button text foreground color back and forth?

Tags: java, swing

I have a **JButton** in my **Nimbus L&F** setting with **MouseListener**. I was able to change the text color when **mouse enter** but cannot change the color back or to **another color** when **mouse exit**. From print out I am sure the mouseExit is called.

Anybody can help me figure out why?

I am thinking after the mouseEntered() is called, the btn_f is not Nimbus L&F anymore. I don't know my guess makes sense or not.

The code likes this:

```
@Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        Object resource = e.getSource();
        if(resource == btn_f)
        {
            System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@====btn_f is enterred");
            UIDefaults defaults = new UIDefaults();
            defaults.put("Button.textForeground", Color.BLUE);
            btn_f.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", defaults);
            //btn_f.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", false);
            //SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(btn_f);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

        Object resource = e.getSource();
        if(resource == btn_f)
        {
            System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@====btn_f is exited");
            UIDefaults defaults = new UIDefaults();
            defaults.put("Button.textForeground", Color.RED);
            btn_f.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides", defaults);
            //btn_f.putClientProperty("Nimbus.Overrides.InheritDefaults", false);
            //SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(btn_f);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [use ButtonModel and events from ChangeListener](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/714968), have to check if is required to call [UIManager.getLookAndFeel().uninitialize();](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10686898/714968)

Answer (score 0):

A simple `btn_f.setForeground( theColor );` works in both enter and `mouseEntered()` and `mouseExited()`.